# Insertar una imagen desde internet en latex

Tags: latex

Estoy intentando insertar una imagen desde Internet en LaTeX, tengo el siguiente código. El enlace es el siguiente http://190.145.116.60/ustamail/Escudo_Usta.png

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\href{http://190.145.116.60/ustamail/Escudo_Usta.png{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{Escudo_Usta.png}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: El código que publicó hace algo diferente: incluye un archivo local y se conecta a un archivo remoto: el camino a seguir está en la respuesta aceptada. Muy bien!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recomendaría descargar la imagen y usarla de manera local.

Tengo entendido que hay manera de correr comandos de shell al compilar (revisa `\write18` y `--shell-escape`), pero algunos compiladores no permiten cualquier comando, más que nada por seguridad.

En servicios web como ShareLaTeX y OverLeaf, lo *más probable* es que no puedas cambiarlo.

---

EDIT: Se me ocurre un ejemplo algo así, usando `wget` (que es una utilería del shell para descargar archivos de Internet.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

% write18 corre wget y guarda la imagen con el nombre de archivo que ya tiene
\write18{wget http://190.145.116.60/ustamail/Escudo_Usta.png}

% Usas el nombre de archivo para incluirla en el documento
\includegraphics{Escudo_Usta.png}

\end{document}
```